# Show nearest neighbors with sklearn KNN

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

I know that after I've fitted a KNN model with sklearn, I can predict the label like this:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
knn.fit([3,1,4,3], [1,0,1,1)]

In: knn.predict([3])
Out: array([0])
```

But is it possible to have KNN display what the nearest neighbors actually are? In pseudo code this would look something like:

```
In: knn.show_nearest_neighbors([3], n_neighbors = 3)
Out: array([3,3,4])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `knn.kneighbors([[3]], n_neighbors=3, return_distance=False)` to get the indices of the neighbors:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
X = np.array([[3],[1],[4],[3]])
knn.fit(X, [1,0,1,1])

l = knn.kneighbors([[3]], n_neighbors=3, return_distance=False)
X[l].ravel()
```

It outputs: `array([3, 3, 4])`.

Comment: Thanks. The `ravel()` is extraneous no?

Comment: The ``ravel()`` is here to get ``array([3, 3, 4])``, otherwise you get ``array([[[3], [3], [4]]])``x